# Querying non unique multi index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe which has repetitive index with different information, I want to sum a column value depending on the value of other 2 columns:

- if 'tipocargo' == 'C' and rfcconcepto is null:

  - then sum those 'cargo' values as 'cargofavor'
- if 'tipocargo' != 'C' and rfcconcepto is not null:

  - then sum 'cargo' values as 'cargocontra'

[image]

I couldn't find a way to do it over the whole df so I retrieve unique index values and iterate them so I ran the code like this:

```py
    chunk         = pd.read_csv (rutaArchivosCSV + nombreArchivo, index_col=False, usecols=columnasLeer, 
                                low_memory=False, chunksize=1000000)
    df_dia        = pd.concat (chunk)
    df_dia        = df_dia[df_dia['cargo'] != 'cargo']
    df_dia        = df_dia.set_index(['numerocliente', 'numerocuenta'])
    #Hacemos drop a las columnas que no se necesitan
    #df_dia        = df_dia.drop (columnasDrop, axis='columns')
    df_dia        = df_dia.sort_index()
    listaClientes = list (df_dia.index.unique())

    for cliente in listaClientes:
        df_cliente = pd.DataFrame(df_dia.loc[cliente], columns=df_dia.columns)

        if int (str (df_cliente['numeromovimiento'].tolist()[0]).strip()) == 0:
            df_cliente['cargofavor']  = 0
            df_cliente['cargocontra'] = 0

            df_aux = pd.DataFrame (index=df_cliente[columnasAux].index)
            df_aux = df_cliente[columnasAux].tail(1).copy()
            #Se renombran los campos segun su mes
            cargoFavorMes  = 'cargofavor' + str(consecutivoCol)
            cargoContraMes = 'cargocontra' + str(consecutivoCol)
            df_aux = df_aux.rename (columns={'cargofavor': cargoFavorMes, 'cargocontra': cargoContraMes})
            #Hacemos drop a las columnas que no se necesitan
            #df_aux = df_aux.drop (columnasDrop, axis='columns')
            df_aux = df_aux.drop (['cargo', 'numeromovimiento', 'rfcconcepto','tipocargo'], axis='columns')
            #Se añade la fila al df final
            df_6_meses = df_6_meses.append (df_aux)
            df_aux = None
```

The problem here is that is way too slow, the iteration grows exponentially slower if the df_dia dataframe is bigger, I don't know how to make it faster.

Comment: keyword is *vectorization*: take out from the loop, and place it above it, any operation that could be done once over the whole dataframe, or the useful subset of it. To begin with: `int (str (df_cliente['numeromovimiento'].tolist()[0]).strip())`, into a temporary column for later use inside the loop, probably. Or *after* the loop: e.g. renaming, dropping i.e. what looks like cleaning-up. In fact, it could be that the whole loop could be avoided this way.

Comment: Posting the famous minimal example *as text* usually encourages people to look into your question.

Comment: Please insert **as text** the output of initial `print(df_dia.to_dict())`  (or a representative part of it, maybe `df_dia.head()`) if you seek more than just general advice. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example